# Python: getting "'socket' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, typeerror

```
def sendToAllClients(messageSender, message):
    # Formatting the message
    messageHeader = f"{len(message) :< {HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
    messageList = {'header': messageHeader, 'data': message.encode('utf-8')}
    # Send the message to all clients
    for client in clients:
        client.send(messageSender['header'] + messageSender['data'] + messageList['header'] + messageList['data'])


def sendMessageTo(messageSender, message, messageTargetUsername):
    # Formatting the message
    messageHeader = f"{len(message) :< {HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
    messageList = {'header': messageHeader, 'data': message.encode('utf-8')}
    # Go through all clients
    for client in clients:
        # If the client has the same username as the target, send the message only to them
        if clients[client].get('data').decode('utf-8') == messageTargetUsername:
            client.send(messageSender['header'] + messageSender['data'] + messageList['header'] + messageList['data'])
```

Im getting the error "TypeError: 'socket' object is not subscriptable" whenever I'm trying to the sendMessageTo method but not when I use the SendToAllClients method, any ideas why this is happening?

The line that seems to be giving the error is:

`client.send(messageSender['header'] + messageSender['data'] + messageList['header'] + messageList['data'])`

But pretty much the same line on sendToAllClients works??

Comment: How do you know that that is the line causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what `clients` is, it will be hard to answer. I will try one thing though.

Instead of

```
if clients[client].get('data').decode('utf-8') == messageTargetUsername:
```

Try

```
if client.get('data').decode('utf-8') == messageTargetUsername:
```

I am assuming here `clients[client]` doesn't have the method `get`, hence you are getting the error. Try and see if that works.

Comment: The part that is getting the error specifically is

 ```client.send(messageSender['header'] + messageSender['data'] + messageList['header'] + messageList['data'])```

But the code in sendToAllClients works:

```client.send(messageSender['header'] + messageSender['data'] + messageList['header'] + messageList['data'])```

Comment: If my answer is not the solution, could you, please paste the actual error, and also provide more information on `clients` and `client` objects.

Comment: So clients is a dictionary of client, client objects are sockets. Here is the error: `File "C:/Users/Nicholas/Documents/GitHub/CS-138/Final/server.py", line 87, in sendMessageTo
    client.send(messageSender['header'] + messageSender['data'] + messageList['header'] + messageList['data'])
TypeError: 'socket' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: In that case you need to provide code that is complete enough to reproduce the error so that someone can help you.